# Returning a Stream from a WCF REST based service to Silverlight application

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-3.0

I've created the following method contract, which returns a `Stream` from a WCF REST based service:

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "path/{id}")]
Stream Get(string id);
```

Implementation:

```
public Stream Get(string id)
{
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";

    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<myXml>some data</MyXml>"));
}
```

A. How do I access this method using `WebRequest`?

Being that this sounds like such an easy question, I suspect that I may be barking up the wrong tree...maybe returning an `XmlElement` is a better approach.

B. What is the recommended way of returning raw XML from a WCF REST based service?

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is [POX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738456.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I will first answer your **second question**

> What is the recommended way of returning raw XML from a WCF REST based service?

Generally there is no recommended way. RESTful API concept is abstracted from data format. On returning `Stream` from HTTP based WCF service I would quote [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc681221.aspx)

> Because the method returns a Stream, WCF assumes that the operation has complete control over the bytes that are returned from the service operation and it applies no formatting to the data that is returned.

And to answer your **first question**, here is a snippet of code that can invoke your implementation

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("location-of-your-endpoint/path/1");
request.Method = "GET";

using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
{
    var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    var theXmlString = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();

    // now you can parse 'theXmlString'
}
```